# encountering an issue with the devTools.send(Network.enable(...)) selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to enable network request block in Chrome dev Tool using selenium java but i am getting error in enable method.
The method enable(Optional, Optional, Optional) in the type Network is not applicable for the arguments (Optional, Optional, Optional)
[image]

I am using Selenium 4.4 and ChromeDriver 121.0.6167.85, JRE 1.7

Here is code:

```
package testpackage;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v102.network.Network;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v102.network.model.RequestWillBeSent;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;  
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;  

public class Test {  
public String baseUrl = "https://google.com";  
String driverPath = "C://chromedriver-win32//chromedriver.exe";  
public WebDriver driver ;   
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Test            
public void test() throws InterruptedException {      
// set the system property for Chrome driver      
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath); 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
// Create driver object for CHROME browser  
//driver = new ChromeDriver();  
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
driver.manage().window().maximize();  
driver.get(baseUrl);  
// get the current URL of the page  
String URL= driver.getCurrentUrl();  
System.out.print(URL);  
//get the title of the page  
String title = driver.getTitle();                  
System.out.println(title); 

Thread.sleep(1000);
DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();
//devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
devTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(), new Consumer<RequestWillBeSent>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(RequestWillBeSent request) {
        System.out.println("Request URL: " + request.getRequest().getUrl());
        System.out.println("Request Method: " + request.getRequest().getMethod());
    }
});

devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));







}     
@BeforeTest  
public void beforeTest() {    
System.out.println("before test");  
}     
@AfterTest  
public void afterTest() {  
driver.quit();  
System.out.println("after test");  
}         
}
```